# Passing Data to D3.js with Django Backend

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, d3.js

I want to build a line chart following the code [here](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_basic.html). I've made slight change to the data being passed with contains epoch time and a closing price. Following is the code

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<body> 
    <h1> Hello! </h1>
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
</body>


<script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Read the data
    var d = {
               "Date":{
                  "0":1641168000000,
                  "1":1641254400000,
                  "2":1641340800000
               },
               "Close":{
                  "0":182.01,
                  "1":179.7,
                  "2":174.92
               }
            };

    
    
    // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
    d3.json(d,
      function(d){
        return { date : d3.timeParse("%s")(d.Date), value : d.Close }
      },
    
      // Now I can use this dataset:
      function(data) {
    
        // Add X axis --> it is a date format
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
          .range([ 0, width ]);
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    
        // Add Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
          .range([ height, 0 ]);
        svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
        // Add the line
        svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
          .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
            )
    
    })
     
</script>
</html>
```

I am unable to generate the graph. I've attached the console screenshot below.

[image]

There seems to be an error passing data as seen in html file below

[image]

I can't figure out how to pass the data, what should be the correct way to do it?

**Edit**

Applied suggested changes as follows

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<body> 
    <h1> Hello! </h1>
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
    <!-- <canvas id="chart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>   -->
    <!-- <script src={% static "js\linechart.js" %}></script>  
    <script>
        var data = {{ AAPL|safe }};

        var chart = LineChart(data, {
        x: d => d.date,
        y: d => d.close,
        yLabel: "↑ Daily close ($)",
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        color: "steelblue"
      });
    
    </script>     -->
</body>


<script>

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    var d = [
       {
         "Date": 1641168000000,
         "Close": 182.01
       },
       {
         "Date": 1641254400000,
         "Close": 179.7
       },
       {
         "Date": 1641168000000,
         "Close": 174.92
       },
    ];

       d3.json(d,
    
      // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
      function(d){
        return { date : d3.timeParse("%s")(d.Date), value : d.Close }
      }).then(
    
      // Now I can use this dataset:
      function(data) {
    
        // Add X axis --> it is a date format
        const x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
          .range([ 0, width ]);
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    
        // Add Y axis
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
          .range([ height, 0 ]);
        svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
        // Add the line
        svg.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
          .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
            )
    
    })
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two things happeningg here:

1. When you call the funciton `d3.json(data, parsingFunction)`, d3 is expecting the data entry to be an array of elements, where each element contains all the information for that entry in your datum. What the parsingFunction does here, is recievee each element in the array and you have to write the logic of how to treat your data (in your case, parse the epoch and keep the close price as it was).

Therefore, what you should do is change the way your data is being sent so that it's an array where each entry is an object containing thee corresponding time and close price, i.e:

```
    var d = [
       {
         "Date": 1641168000000,
         "Close": 182.01
       },
       {
         "Date": 1641254400000,
         "Close": 179.7
       },
       {
         "Date": 1641168000000,
         "Close": 174.92
       },
    ];
```

2. This is actually not what's causing your mistake, but I'll say it because i saw it in your code: `d3.json` return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Which means you have to wait for it to arrive. You can do this by either explicitely using `var data = await d3.json(.., ..)` and then using data to do whatever you want. OR, specify a callback function (which is what you were trying to do, I believe). To do that though, you need too specify that you want to call that function when the promise has resolved, by using a `.then(callback)` statement.

And by doing that, you can correctly parse the data with the code you sent above:

```
d3.json(d, function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%s")(d.Date), value : d.Close }
    }
).then(function(data){
     // Use the data
})
```

Comment: I've made the suggested changes see the edit part. Still can't get it working? Have you tried the solution at your end?